# Is a watch Chatzitzah for tefillin shel yad

Tags: halacha, tefilin, hands-fingers, chatzitzah, orach-chaim

According to Halacha does a watch count as Chatzitzah which invalidates tefillin shel yad? So for an average sized wrist watch, is the size between the Arm and arm tefillin strap enough to invalidate the mitzvah?

Is this question discussed/ruled on by any major poskim?

Comment: Do you mean, is the lack of contact between the strap of the tefillin and the arm where the watch is positioned, enough to invalidate the mitzvah of the tefillo shel yad?

Comment: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Putting_On_and_Removing_Tefillin#Physical_Separation/Chatzitza

Comment: The answer *m'ikar hadin* is no and I see many who don't remove their watch but Rav Binyamin Tabady told me it was good to remove the watch and I see now R Ovadia Yosef rules accordingly. Doesn't take long.